# Create a class and a static function which take classid as argument and returns all names of the students in that class as a list

Tags: apex, string

i created an apex class where i pass the class name and it will give me a list of all the students in it  but i want to give className as string but it's only taking the id of the class.

## Here Classs__c is a lookup field on Student__c object.

```
public class AllStudentsInClass
{
    public static list<Student__c> studentInClass(String sName)
    {  
        
list<Student__c> retList = [Select id, name from Student__c Where Classs__c=:sName];

        system.debug('the student data is '+retList);
        Return retList;   
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the static method?

Comment: It’s straight forward, chane your filter to: ‘Classs__r.Name=:sName’

Comment: @SantanuBoral      AllStudentsInClass.studentInClass('a017F00000DSLghQAH');

in execution window

Comment: @RahulSharma i found this error                                                                                          
id, name from Student__c Where Classs__r=:sName
                               ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:39
No such column 'Classs__r' on entity 'Student__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Also, You can modify your query like this - [Select id, name from Student__c Where Classs__c IN (Select Id from Classs where Name =: sName)]. Before trying this troubleshoot @RahulSharma answer's his solution must work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Santanu Boral and #Rahul sharma thanx for reviewing the answer

the problem was when rahul suggest to use relationship as #Classs__r it throw error as it need to add the field also so i just add #Classs__r.name and it worked